# Prevent Reloading The Page After Clicking The Like Button

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have written code to like a publication, where clicking the like button saves the value to the database using server-side code. However, when I click the button, the page refreshes to save the value, and I'm experiencing some issues. I attempted to use JavaScript code like `event.preventDefault()`, but it didn't work. Could you suggest a better way to implement this?

```
                echo '<form method="POST" action="profile.php" id="likeForm">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_' . $publication_id . '" value="' . $publication_id . '">';
                echo '<div class="button-container">';
                echo '<button type="submit" id="likeButton" onsubmit="return false;">' . $heart_icon . '</button>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</form>';
```

I tried `event.preventDefault()`,
I also tried this code:

```
echo '<form method="POST" action="profile.php" id="likeForm">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_' . $publication_id . '" value="' . $publication_id . '">';
echo '<div class="button-container">';
echo '<button type="button" id="likeButton">' . $heart_icon . '</button>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</form>';

echo '<script>';
echo 'document.getElementById("likeButton").addEventListener("click", function() {';
echo 'var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();';
echo 'xhr.open("POST", "profile.php");';
echo 'xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");';
echo 'xhr.onload = function() {';
echo 'if (xhr.status === 200) {';
echo 'console.log(xhr.responseText);'; // or you can show a success message here
echo '}';
echo '};';
echo 'xhr.send("id_' . $publication_id . '=' . $publication_id . '");';
echo '});';
echo '</script>';
```

And lastly this one:

```
$(function() {
        $('#likeForm').on('submit', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'profile.php',
                data: $('#likeForm').serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    alert("Data has been submitted!");
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Comment: i think ```e.preventDefault();``` should come before ```$('#likeForm').on('submit', function(e)``` else you have already executed the code if not placed beforehand... you will also need to pass event in function ```$(function(e) {e.preventDefault();```

Comment: @AnantV '  $(function() {
    $('#likeForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'profile.php',
            data: $('#likeForm').serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert("Data has been submitted!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});'
I made this but page still reloads. I also deleted onsubmit from button and it is still the same. I have to make this buton like nothing works. ,

Comment: you are using $ sign ... are you using jquery and have you added it ....

Comment: @AnantV     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
Yes, I added this to the <head>.

Answer (score 0):

Preventdefault doesn't work for a submit, you should use return false to prevent the form to submit.

Try putting it in your success too.

Comment: I did this after you said but still the same. When I click the button, page reloads. $(function() {
    $('#likeForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'profile.php',
            data: $('#likeForm').serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert("Data has been submitted!");
            }
        });
        return false; // return false to prevent form submission
    });
});

Comment: And if you delete your Ajax Fonction and juste put return false in your submit function what is happening ?

Comment: Same thing. Page reloads as before. Nothing changes.

Comment: Ok I see. Are you sure your JavaScript works ? If it works then try to change with $(document).on('submit', '#likeForm', function()) or $('#likeForm').submit()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the event so the default behavior is discarded.
Please try this.

```
$(function() {
        $('#likeForm').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'profile.php',
                data: $('#likeForm').serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    alert("Data has been submitted!");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Still the same issue. The page still reloads.

Answer (score 0):

Please find your edited code below and try it. I have try to make it simpler

```
  <form method="POST"  id="likeForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_<?php echo $publication_id;?>" value="<?php echo $publication_id;?>">
        <div class="button-container">
    <button type="submit" id="likeButton" onsubmit="return false;"><?php echo  $heart_icon;?> </button>
    </div>
  </form>


<!--jquery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<!--custom code -->
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('#likeForm').on('submit', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'profile.php',
                data: $('#likeForm').serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    alert("Data has been submitted!");
                }
            });
           
        });
  
</script>
```

---

**TIP and NOTE**:

1. When developing in case of javascript as soon as you load page please check the
   console for any errors.
2. Because php is able to interprit the html file we can make code more readable by injecting the php in html rather than doing vice versa as i have done.
3. When using jquery or any other library please make sure that your custom code always comes last in order.
4. Its a good practice to place all the javascript before the end of `</body>` tag

---

**In case of query or issue please leave a comment.**

Comment: Thank you so much for your information. I took out the code from PHP. And I did the things you said with your given code but it is still not working :/

Comment: can you add image of your browser console to your question  so that we can have better understanding..... like what kind of error you are getting....

Comment: @emir By the way i tested my code and it worked fine... also make sure to clear your browser cache. shortcut crtl+F5.... please add image of the browser console to help us understand your position better

Comment: I don't see any error. There is just. some warning messages that has nothing to do with the like button. I closed my PC right now. I am going to send you an image a little bit later but it is not working. I am going to try your code in another page in my ide.

Comment: hi again mate! thank you so much for your help and time. I nested the code given by you and it kind of works but there are some things that should be fixed. The biggest problem is, when I click the button, that just works for the last publication. I think I have to give each of the like buttons a unique id to work them each. So I can make that. The second problem is, when I click the like button, it turns from <far fa-heart> to <fas fa heart> icon but with the code you provided, I have to reload the page to see that transition. I can fix them but can you check it out if you have time?

Comment: Hi, if you find this answer useful you can accept it... furthermore. i am bit confused and unable to understand your position... i will be happy to help you further but instead of continuing here in comment (as discussions are not allowed on SO) .. you can connect with me directly... just drop me a mail given on my profile and we can discuss your issues in detail. ...